# vsts: branch "users/<username>" organization for git repos

Tags: git, visual-studio

For Visual Studio Team Services in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/manage-your-branches in the following screenshot you can see how branches can be organized so there is a "folder" per user. Where can you set this up?

[image]

In other views you can see how this looks in vs:

[image]

Creating Git Branches in Visual Studio

But how do you create "users/frank"?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `users/frank` as a branch. But you can't then create `users/frank/somefeature`. You can't create "child branches".
Just create the branch locally with the full name `users/frank` and then publish it to VSTS from Visual Studio or push from the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't create sub/child branches (as **jessehouwing** said), you can create the *appearance* of a nested branch in the way it is named.

For example, to re-create the branch shown in the image you referred to; just create a single branch called `users/frank/test-css-changes`.

VSTS and Visual Studio will treat all that comes before the last `/` as the "folder" name and nest the remaining text as the branch name, like so:

- **users/frank**

  - *test-css-changes*

But, as far as I understand, this hierarchy is purely for *display* - it is really just a single branch called `users/frank/test-css-changes`.

Hope this helps! :o)